# How can I set the column width of a Property Grid?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, propertygrid

I am using property grid in my application to display the name and value of the properties of an object.

By default the width of the columns (name and property) are at a ratio of 50:50.
and we have an option of sliding the splitter to change this width.
I would like to know how this width can be adjusted programmatically so that it can be set at say 25:75.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5152195/359170) answer is mentioned :

There is no property to do that and you have to hack the control. first add this code :

```
    public static void SetLabelColumnWidth(PropertyGrid grid, int width)
{
    if (grid == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("grid");

    // get the grid view
    Control view = (Control)grid.GetType().GetField("gridView", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(grid);

    // set label width
    FieldInfo fi = view.GetType().GetField("labelWidth", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    fi.SetValue(view, width);

    // refresh
    view.Invalidate();
}
```

and call it with the size what you want . like this:

```
SetLabelColumnWidth(propertyGrid1, 100);
```

Comment: Field name "labelWidth" not exist! Still, size is 50:50!

Comment: I use .Net 4.5 in my project and there is no problem with code.

Comment: How can I change code for .Net 4 ? In .Net 4, code can't change the width of column !

Comment: Doesn't do anything in .NET 4.0.

Comment: This worked fine for me, however note that both selecting the object, and resizing the control, will re-apply the 50:50. You'll need to call SetLabelColumnWidth() after each object selection, and resize, in order to maintain it.

Comment: Using reflection to access private internals of a framework control *is a terrible idea*.  There's no way of knowing when this will break.  Hell, even a security update to the framework could break this, meaning your application could break after a Windows Update is installed.

Encapsulation exists for a reason.  Don't poke inside of things.

Answer (score 16):

I found that the solution of hamed doesn't work reliably. I have solved it by programmatically simulating the user dragging the column splitter. The following code uses reflection to do this:

```
public static void SetLabelColumnWidth(PropertyGrid grid, int width)
{
    if(grid == null)
        return;

    FieldInfo fi = grid.GetType().GetField("gridView", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    if(fi == null)
        return;

    Control view = fi.GetValue(grid) as Control;
    if(view == null)
        return;

    MethodInfo mi = view.GetType().GetMethod("MoveSplitterTo", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    if(mi == null)
        return;
    mi.Invoke(view, new object[] { width });
}
```

Comment: Works but has to be called after the form was built (in Form_Load event or later).

Comment: This does work, but it needs to be called when the PropertyGrid is already visible, not just loaded. I've bound this code to the Resize event, which occurs after showing the control by a button click.

Comment: You can shorten this quite a bit using the new C# 6 null-propagation syntax: http://pastebin.com/3TEHBPYs

Comment: How did you find the name of the method "MoveSplitterTo" ? I am thinking how can I make the label column to always fit contents. @Nic

Comment: I used reflector to see how the splitter was handled in the PropertyGrid.

Comment: In a Framework 3.5 app, this didn't work for me. GetField on gridView returns null.

Comment: Works on Net.4.7 !

Answer (score 8):

**2019 Answer**

Other answers on this page contain adhoc improvements over the course of C# versions and user comments.

I picked the best working solution and created an Extension method.

```
public static class PropGridExtensions
{
    public static void SetLabelColumnWidth(this PropertyGrid grid, int width)
    {
        FieldInfo fi = grid?.GetType().GetField("gridView", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        Control view = fi?.GetValue(grid) as Control;
        MethodInfo mi = view?.GetType().GetMethod("MoveSplitterTo", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        mi?.Invoke(view, new object[] { width });
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

In Form_Load() event, call it directly on your property grid like so:

myPropertyGrid.SetLabelColumnWidth(value);

You shouldn't need to call it anywhere else. Call once and enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

Version for Framework 4.0 (I had to use **BaseType**). Method is used in class inherited from PropertyGrid:

```
private void SetLabelColumnWidth(int width)
{
    FieldInfo fi = this.GetType().BaseType.GetField("gridView", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    object view = fi.GetValue(this);
    MethodInfo mi = view.GetType().GetMethod("MoveSplitterTo", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    mi.Invoke(view, new object[] { width });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had success with the open source extended PropertyGrid you can find at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13630/Add-Custom-Properties-to-a-PropertyGrid. It has two methods you'd be interested in:

> AutoSizeProperties - Move automatically the splitter to better fit all
>   the properties shown. MoveSplitterTo - Move the splitter as indicated
>   by the user in the parameter.

You could calculate 25% of the `Width` of the PropertyGrid and set `MoveSplitterTo` with it.

I actually use `AutoSizeProperties` though, as it automatically moves the splitter to snuggly fit the labels. Note that you need to set `AutoSizeProperties` after you set the `SelectedObject`.

Answer (score 0):

A special use case, that might be useful for someone:
I'm using PropertyGrid with a DesignSurface and label column width is narrowing by every value edit. To keep the label column width as the user has set it before the following worked for me:

```
public UcPropertyGridHost(...)
        {
            ...
            propGrid.PropertyValueChanged += OnPropertyValueChanged;
        }

private void OnPropertyValueChanged(object p_s, PropertyValueChangedEventArgs p_e)
        {
            var iWidth = GetLastLabelWidth();

            //do other things you want to

            SetLabelColumnWidth(propGrid, (int)iWidth);
        }

private int GetLastLabelWidth()
        {
            var iDefaultLabelColumnWidth = propGrid.Width / 2;

            var oFieldInfo = propGrid.GetType().GetField("gridView", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            if (oFieldInfo == null) return iDefaultLabelColumnWidth;

            if (!(oFieldInfo.GetValue(propGrid) is Control oView)) return iDefaultLabelColumnWidth;

            var oFileInfo = oView.GetType().GetField("labelWidth", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            if (oFileInfo == null) return iDefaultLabelColumnWidth;

            return (int)oFileInfo.GetValue(oView);
        }
```

and the code taken from here:

```
private void SetLabelColumnWidth(PropertyGrid p_oGrid, int p_iWidth)
    {
        if (p_oGrid == null) return;

        var oFieldInfo = p_oGrid.GetType().GetField("gridView", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        if (oFieldInfo == null) return;

        if (!(oFieldInfo.GetValue(p_oGrid) is Control oView)) return;

        var oMethodInfo = oView.GetType().GetMethod("MoveSplitterTo", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        if (oMethodInfo == null) return;

        oMethodInfo.Invoke(oView, new object[] { p_iWidth });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since getting the field `gridView` didn't work for me, I made another approach, where you can get the GridView from the `Controls` property.

The GridView, however, is of type `System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGridInternal.PropertyGridView`, which is, you guessed it, internal.

But, all we care about at this point is a control that actually has the method `MoveSplitterTo`, so we enumerate the controls until we get what we want, and then just call the method.

```
    public class PropertyGridEx : PropertyGrid
    {
        private int splitterPosition;
        public int SplitterPosition
        {
            get => splitterPosition;
            set
            {
                splitterPosition = value;

                foreach (var control in Controls)
                {
                    if (control.GetType().GetMethod("MoveSplitterTo", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic) is MethodInfo method)
                    {
                        method.Invoke(control, new object[] { value });
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

you can use [Smart PropertyGrid.Net](http://www.visualhint.com/propertygrid) instead of propertygrid and change the ratio with this code:

```
propertyGrid1.LabelColumnWidthRatio = 0.25;
```

Comment: Please guess to me free component!